# Task management software, Java EE / JBoss

Tags: task-management, api

Our main application is based on JBOSS/Seam and utilizes jBPMN for business processes. A large part of the application are task lists for employees.

Requirements for the task lists are (rough):

- Task / Subtask (certain set of task, like approve an application, administer comments, etc.)
- Predefined status model for tasks (open, in progress, rejected, closed)
- Assignees / assigned groups
- scheduled follow-ups
- comments
- Integration with our core system (design, processes)

We use JiRA for our IT, but not in the service part of the company, who needs to work with the task lists. It offers most of the above, comes with an extensive API which makes it possible to integrate with our business processes. However, I think it is a little bit too heavy for this task.

So what I am looking for is a light weight task management solution with the above features and an API. No SaaS.

Or is it better to just rely on JBOSS / jBPMN features? Make or buy?

Comment: What types of work are you tasking out?  I think of Jira as (while very flexible and easy to customize) a fairly light weight tool.  I guess, with Jira in place why bring in something else?  What about Jira is a concern?  That should help narrow this a little.

Comment: Thanks @James, you are right. JiRA is a great tool. However, we want a deeper integration in our system, not forcing people to use two different tools. I think this is possible by using the extensive REST API of v6.2. Tasks are mostly centered around service and finance topics like contract management, dunning, invoicing. The difference to JiRA's designated use is that the issues are predefined, not like a usual programmer's ticket where the description (requirements) are key. We just need the workflow and status model.